# If $(X_n,f(X_n))$ converges in distribution to $(X,Y)$, can we say that $Y=g(X)$ for some $g$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables and let $f$ be a measurable function. If $(X_n,f(X_n))$ converges in distribution to $(X,Y)$, can we say that $Y=g(X)$ for some $g$?

If $f$ is continuous, then by the continuous mapping theorem we have that $f(X_n)$ converges in distribution to $f(X)$. But what if $f$ is merely measurable?

Comment: If $\mu_X$ is the law of $X$ and $f$ is discontinuous in a set of $\mu_X$-measure $0$, then $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(X)$ in distributions.

Comment: If $f$ is allowed to depend on $n$, the answer is definitely no, and the final variables $X,Y$ can be independent. I think it also works for $f$ fixed with a bit of work. Do that by taking a set of points in the square $[0,1]^2$ which approaches a uniform distribution.

Comment: @Mittens Sure we can weaken continuous mapping theorem to continuous a.s. By Doob-Dynkin what I'm asking is if $Y$ is measurable wrt $\sigma(X)$ or not

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam $f$ is not allowed to depend on $n$

Answer (score 3):

Please notice following example. Let
\begin{gather*}
 X_n=\frac{\xi}{n},   \quad \xi\stackrel{d}{=}N(0,1),\\
 f(x)=\begin{cases} 1,\qquad & x>0,\\
  0,& x=0,\\
  -1,& x<0.
 \end{cases}
\end{gather*}
Then, as $n\to\infty$,
\begin{gather*}
 X_n\stackrel{pr}{\to}0, \\
 f(X_n)\stackrel{d}{=}\eta, \qquad \begin{cases}
  \mathsf{P}(\eta=1)=\frac12,\\
  \mathsf{P}(\eta=-1)=\frac12.  
 \end{cases} \\
 (X_n,f(X_n)) \stackrel{d}{\to}(0,\eta).  
\end{gather*}
But $\eta\neq f(0)$ .